# Will disposing an object that has a thread started on its method remove the need to call Thread.Abort()

Tags: .net

Consider the following code using the .Net 2003 Framework.

```
' This gets initialized in New() perhaps... 
Private someObject As SomeClass

Public Sub startThread()
    Dim t As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf someObject.someSub)
    t.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    someObject.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Will someObject.Dispose() effectively remove the need to call `t.Abort()`?

Comment: That depends on the implementation of the `Dispose` method in that object, it's not "automatic" or anything. It might cause trouble, of course.

Comment: That sounds like the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure of the *exact* behaviour of the runtime if you dispose of an object whilst a referenced method is running in another thread. My *guess* is the thread would throw an exception which would effectively cause an abort, however, it's not a documented process. Also, it's not a particularly great idea to call Abort on a thread directly because the behaviour can be erratic and not guarenteed.

Comment: Thanks @James.  Your comment lead me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
Public Sub startThread()
    Dim t As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf someObject.someSub)
    t.Start()
End Sub
```

You are getting a reference to a subroutine that happens to be in someObject. someObject will have no way to know that this method has been called as a worker thread outside of an object. Because of that you will be forced to stop the thread yourself. Abort is a sledgehammer. If someSub is written properly there should be a way to make the thread exit gracefully and then there is no need to Abort.

```
Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    someObject.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Because someObject wasn't responsible in the creation of the thread (it had one of its methods used as a thread) it doesn't bear a responsibility in its termination. So in the design pattern you have `someObject.Dispose()` won't be able to terminate the thread. You'll have to do it yourself.

If you have the ability to change someClass a proper design pattern would be to create a new method like `startThread`. `t` would be a member variable in someClass. startThread would in turn do something like:

```
t = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Me.someSub) 
t.Start()
```

Now someClass was responsible for the thread creation so in someClass's Dispose method you would attempt to stop the thread (hopefully with more grace than Abort.